# solve the integral, it is related to the Cauchy distribution

Tags: integration

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x\cdot \frac{1}{\pi\left(1+x^{2}\right)}\cdot\left(\left(\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan\left(x\right)\right)^{2}-\frac{1}{4}\right)^{n}dx $$
$$ n \in N , n>0  $$
I noticed that

$$ \left(\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan\left(x\right)\right)' = \frac{1}{\pi\left(1+x^{2}\right)}$$
but I don't fully understand how to apply it, if we replace the variable, we get
$$ \frac{1}{\pi}\arctan\left(x\right)=t $$
$$ \frac{1}{\pi\left(1+x^{2}\right)}dx = dt $$
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x\cdot\left(t^{2}-\frac{1}{4}\right)^{n}dt $$
but **t(x) = 1/pi * arctan(x)** , so we can't just take **x** as the sign of the integral.
Many calculators like desmos easily solve this integral and the answer is **0**, but I just can't get to that

Comment: Is the integrand an odd function?

Comment: i guess yes. x - odd , 1/(pi*(1+x^2)) -  even, and arctan(x)^2 0 even too. thanks a lot, then I can refer to the integration property of an odd function, but it's kind of weird why for n = 0 this integral will be undefined.